# pyvenv vs venv vs python-virtualenv vs virtualenv and python 3

Tags: apt, python, pip, virtualenv

```
malikarumi@Tetouan2:~$ pip install virtualenv
    Collecting virtualenv
    Downloading virtualenv-12.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
    100% |################################| 1.8MB 330kB/s 

malikarumi@Tetouan2:~$ pip freeze
    (a lot of stuff, but not virtualenv)

malikarumi@Tetouan2:~$ virtualenv testvenv1
    The program 'virtualenv' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
    sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

What is going on here? is python-virtualenv == pyvenv? Isn't that still broken? Does original virtualenv still work with python?
if venv (too many name variations!!!) is part of the standard library, https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html, why am I being told to install it?

And when I did try to install it, I got:

```
malikarumi@Tetouan2:~$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
    python-colorama python-distlib python-html5lib python-pip python-setuptools
```

At which point I aborted, because installing python3-pip just before that had given me

```
Setting up python3-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-pip (1.5.4-1) ...
```

And I wasn't sure if the extra packages would overwrite them or go onto python 2.7.

I read that python 3 is supposed to be the default going forward. Since both 2.7 and 3.4 are there, and have separate commands, how do I not only make sure Python 3 is my default, but that anything I install goes there and is used by it instead of 2.7?

BTW, I tried sudo apt-get python3-virtualenv and got: E: Unable to locate package python3-virtualenv

Comment: I'd still like to know what the difference - if any - is between all these different but similarly named virtual environment packages.

Comment: I'm using 14.04, so [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/854838/181442) helped me.

Answer (score 4):

The way to install Python 3.x packages in a Python virtual environment is to create the Python virtual environment using Python 3 virtual environment creator (*python3-virtualenv*). python3-virtualenv is in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 14.10 and later.

#### Install Python 3.x packages in a Python virtual environment in 16.04 and later

1. Install Python 3 virtual environment creator

   ```
    sudo apt install virtualenv python3-virtualenv
   ```
2. Create a Python virtual environment for python3. You can only install python3 packages inside this Python virtual environment. If you also want to install Python 2.x packages, then you need to make another Python virtual environment.

   ```
    virtualenv -p python3 venv  
    source ./venv/bin/activate
   ```

   The new Python virtual environment for python3 will be created in the `venv` directory which is located in the current directory.
3. Install Python packages.

   ```
   cd /path/to/venv/ # venv is the python3 virtual environment's directory
    source bin/activate
    python3 -m pip install first-package-name next-package-name last-package-name
   ```

This is a new python3 virtual environment with the latest version of pip3, so installing Python packages in it will work great.

---

#### Install Python 3.x packages in a Python virtual environment in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper  
gedit .bashrc
```

Add the following line to the end of .bashrc.

```
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Save the changes to .bashrc and close gedit. Source your .bashrc for the changes to take effect.

```
cd 
source .bashrc
```

Create a Python virtual environment for python3. You can only install python3 packages inside this Python virtual environment. If you also want to install Python 2.x packages, then you need to make another Python virtual environment.

```
mkvirtualenv py3 -p /usr/bin/python3
```

The new Python virtual environment for python3 will be created in the `~/.virtualenvs/py3` directory. `.virtualenvs` is a hidden folder.

Install a package.

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/py3
source bin/activate
python2 -m pip install package-name
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. Vivid (15.04) has `python3-virtualenv` and `python3-venv` packages available. I'm assuming `python3-venv` is the correct package, in which case I have no idea what purpose `python3-virtualenv` serves.

Comment: Incorrect. You can use `virtualenv` (executable) to create environment with arbitrary interpreter,  including PyPy, just fine  E.g. `virtualenv -p python3 newenv`.

Comment: What is the relation between `python3-venv` and `python3-virtualenv`? The first one is recommended by Ubuntu (`Command 'pyvenv' not found, but can be installed with`) but installing it fails to change anything.

Comment: @reducingactivity First run the command `apt show python3-venv python3-virtualenv` and leave the terminal open for reference. Then read the accepted answer to [What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573587/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it gets complicated. The following is shown against Ubuntu Xenial (which is underlying release for Linux Mint I use). Let's sort it out:

#### pyvenv

It refers to the Python 3.3+ [stdlib package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)'s wrapper script. But it was deprecated since Python 3.6.

It is also a [PyPi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenv), which is a virtual environment switcher.

#### venv

It's the Python 3.3+ [stdlib package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) whose purpose was to improve and replace the PyPi [virtualenv package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (see [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/)). But it seems it's not there yet (at least not as feature-complete).

#### python-virtualenv and virtualenv

```
$ apt-cache show virtualenv | grep Depends
Depends: python3, python3-virtualenv
```

As you can see it runs on Python 3. `python-virtualenv` package is meant to be used like `python2 -m virtualenv py2`. Let's see how `virtualenv` works on fresh Ubuntu Xenial (`docker run --rm -it ubuntu:xenial`):

```
$ virtualenv
bash: virtualenv: command not found
$ apt-get update
...
$ apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates dh-python libexpat1 libmpdec2 libpython3-stdlib
  libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0
  mime-support openssl python-pip-whl python3 python3-minimal
  python3-pkg-resources python3-virtualenv python3.5 python3.5-minimal
Suggested packages:
  libdpkg-perl python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python3-setuptools
  python3.5-venv python3.5-doc binutils binfmt-support
Recommended packages:
  file
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates dh-python libexpat1 libmpdec2 libpython3-stdlib
  libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0
  mime-support openssl python-pip-whl python3 python3-minimal
  python3-pkg-resources python3-virtualenv python3.5 python3.5-minimal
  virtualenv
...
$ virtualenv test
The executable python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist
$ virtualenv -p python3 py3 
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /py3/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /py3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
$ . py3/bin/activate
(py3) $ python --version
Python 3.5.2
(py3) $ deactivate
$ apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends python    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libffi6 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib
  python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc binutils binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libffi6 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python
  python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
...
$ virtualenv py2 
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /py2/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /py2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
$ . py2/bin/activate
(py2) $ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

As you can see even though `virtualenv` package is using `python3-virtualenv`, its default is to create Python 2 environment.

Comment: I have also noticed the same thing on my machine which was running Ubuntu 14.04 at the time.  - *"As you can see even though virtualenv package is using python3-virtualenv, its default is to create Python 2 environment."*