# virtualenvwrapper + python3: invalid syntax

Tags: python3, virtualenvwrapper

On Ubuntu 14.04 I run

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 myvenv
```

And I get

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 37, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 39, in <module>
    import configparser as ConfigParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser.py", line 397
    _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from configparser import ConfigParser, NoOptionError, NoSectionError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser.py", line 397
    _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 37, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 39, in <module>
    import configparser as ConfigParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser.py", line 397
    _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It visibly is trying to install a python3 virtualenv using python2. How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pyvenv vs venv vs python-virtualenv vs virtualenv and python 3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/603935/pyvenv-vs-venv-vs-python-virtualenv-vs-virtualenv-and-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so weird. I had solved this and I ran into this once more. My old suggestion wasn't enough.

This time I had to uninstall pip and pip3 and then reinstall them. I think my pip version was installed in a very weird fashion using easy_install, but I could uninstall it using:

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
```

Then I reinstalled pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it.

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

That simple.

Answer (score 1):

The `virtualenv.py` should be compatible between python2.7 and python3.4.0. And yours is excepting because the python3 version cannot load the (renamed) `ConfigParser` module.

You seem to be running an older version of `virtualenvwrapper`. On my system `virtualenv.py` looks like:

```
try:
    import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    import configparser as ConfigParser
```

around line 37 (virtualenvwrapper version 4.6.0), and that just falls back to using the new name `configparser`

You can try to upgrade using:

```
sudo pip install -U virtualenvwrapper
```

if you originally installed `virtualenvwrapper` with `pip`