# Python3-venv not installed ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python3

Fresh install of ubuntu gnome 14.04, followed by dist-upgrade

one of the first things I tried to do was create virtual environment for python

```
python3 -m venv flask
```

gave me

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.
```

which is odd because i thought venv was installed by default, but anyways

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

gives me

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-venv
```

am I missing something? is something wrong with my python installation? i've tried to google whether there's a repo or something i need but I can't find one.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-venv says it's for 15.04 and newer.

Answer (score 36):

Do :

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv
```

and then you can easily do :

```
python3 -m venv flask
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34272200/2736559)

Comment: Does not work with Python 3.6