# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when install pandas latest version

Tags: python3, pandas

I am installing pandas new version 1.0.3 using below command
pip3 install pandas.

But I am getting below error

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/79/f236ab1cfde94bac03d7b58f3f2ab0b1cc71d6a8bda3b25ce370a9fe4ab1/pandas-1.0.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-d_rfkjs6/pandas/setup.py", line 42
        f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}",
                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-d_rfkjs6/pandas/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried installing pandas from below command

```
apt-get install python3-pandas
```

This commands work But it installs the old version of pandas.

I am using python 3.5 version and wanted to install latest version of pandas 1.0.3

Comment: Did you ever hear of a thing called a [Python virtual environment](https://askubuntu.com/a/603937)?

Comment: I have no problems with `pip3 install pandas` on 19.10, python 3.7, pip 18.1. So specify your specs: `pip3 --version`, `cat /etc/lsb-release` by editing your question.

Comment: I was also able to install it on 16.04, but it installs old version of pandas: 0.24.... Also, do what it asks: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1):

Your error says you need to upgrade your pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Or you could also try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then `pip3` -V should show you correct version it mentioned about.

Then try installing pandas using `pip3 install pandas`

On 19.10 it installs the latest version, but on 16.04 it installs older version. I think, [it's because of](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html) newer versions of pandas do not support python 3.5:

> **Python version support**
>   Officially Python 3.6.1 and above, 3.7, and 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Pandas 1.0.3 requires python 3.6.1 or above. So you would have to upgrade python first. I would look to see if switching to a higher version of python is an option, otherwise, you can only use pandas 0.25 on python 3.5.